# Add Multiple Middleware to Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-middleware

I'm new to laravel I have created middleware for my each role but when I add it to my route it won't work.

If I add single middleware to my route it works fine but when I add second and third one It will not work.

It won't shows the route to authorized `user` it redirect it to home,

My User Model:

```
public function IsAdmin()
{
    if($this->role_id =='1')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public function IsManager()
{
    if($this->role_id =='2')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public function IsUser()
{
    if($this->role_id =='3')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My Kernal:

```
'IsAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin::class,
'IsManager' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsManager::class,
'IsUser' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsUser::class,
```

My IsAdmin Middlewares:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user =Auth::User();
    if(!$user->IsAdmin())
    {
        return redirect('stock');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

My IsManager

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user =Auth::User();
    if(!$user->IsManager())
    {
        return redirect('stock');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

and IsUser

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user =Auth::User();
    if(!$user->IsUser())
    {
        return redirect('stock');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

and finally my Route

```
Route::get('approv',['middleware'=>['IsManager','IsAdmin'],function(){
    return view('approv');
}]);
```

Comment: What is the error? you just say i does not work? what do you see, what do you expect?

Comment: it won't show the route to authorized user it redirect it to stock page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work as you'd expect. **All** middleware need to pass in order for the request to be processed which means that your user will need to be both a manager and an admin at the same time which based on your setup is impossible.

You can get around this (kind of) by making a different kind of middleware:

Kernel:

```
'roles' => \App\Http\Middleware\Roles::class,
```

And the Roles middleware:

```
class Roles {

    private function checkRole($role) {
          switch ($role) {
              case 'user': return \Auth::user()->IsUser();
              case 'manager': return \Auth::user()->IsManager();
              case 'admin': return \Auth::user()->IsAdmin();
          }
          return false;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles) 
    {
         foreach ($roles as $role) {
             if ($this->checkRole($role)) {
                 //At least one role passes
                 return $next($request);
             }
         } 
         //All checks failed so user does not have any of the required roles
         return redirect('stock');  
    }
}
```

Then to use this you simply do:

```
Route::get('approv',['middleware'=>['roles:manager,admin'],function(){
   return view('approv');
}]);
```

This works because Laravel Middleware support parameters. You can pass parameters as a comma separated list of strings where you declare the middleware. In this case this was done as `roles:`**`manager,admin`**

Laravel will then send these parameters as additional parameters in the `handle` method. These can be accessed using PHPs syntax for variadic arguments. In this particular case it's by using the array spread operator. This is documented as an example in the [function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) section of the PHP manual.

Note that this is actually equivalent to saying :

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role1=null, $role2=null, $role3=null)
```

but using the spread operator is much more convenient since `...$roles` would be an array which contains only the roles that were passed in the middleware.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I copied your code and paste it in my project now it gives my this error          "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: wow you guys are genius it worked could you please explain what dose this mean "...$roles" triple dots. thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer with a short explanation. In short it just indicates that `handle` will take a variable number of arguments and those extra arguments are going to be accessible as an array in `$roles` .